# Extract currency code from $orders

Tags: commerce

I'm trying to extract the currency code for the current order, I printed the $order variable using print_r, but I'm not at all a PHP programmer and I don't really know how to extract the currency code, I can see it there, but I don't know how to extract it, can somebody point me to the right direction? I will be delighted if I will learn how to do this kind of actions.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The currency data lives in the `commerce_order_total` field by default. You can extract that information easily using `field_get_items()`, though an `entity_metadata_wrapper()` is just more fun:

```
$order = commerce_order_load($order_id);
$order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);

$currency_code = $order_wrapper->commerce_order_total->currency_code->value();
```